# AngularJS count JSON array

Tags: angularjs, json

Please help me, I have angularJS code like this :

```
.state('masterpegawai.alltalenta', {
            url: '/alltalenta',
            templateUrl: 'public/js/partial-masterpegawai-alltalenta.html',
            controller:function($scope,$http,$interval){
                    $http.get('http://10.16.107.77:3000/allhistorytalenta').success(function(data){

                        $scope.listtalentapegawai=data;

                    });
            }
        })
```

That produce JSON like this :

```
[{
    "nip": "6080022A",
    "nama": "ASLAN PURNAMA",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": null,
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": "Potensial",
    "semester1_2015": null
}, {
    "nip": "6080022A",
    "nama": "ASLAN PURNAMA",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": null,
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": null,
    "semester1_2015": "Potensial"
}, {
    "nip": "6080038A",
    "nama": "SYAIFUL ANWAR",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": null,
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": "Potensial",
    "semester1_2015": null
}, {
    "nip": "6080038A",
    "nama": "SYAIFUL ANWAR",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": null,
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": null,
    "semester1_2015": "Potensial"
}, {
    "nip": "6080048A",
    "nama": "NURHAYATI",
    "semester1_2012": null,
    "semester2_2012": null,
    "semester1_2013": "Potensial",
    "semester2_2013": null,
    "semester1_2014": null,
    "semester2_2014": null,
    "semester1_2015": null
}]
```

I Would like to count the array key and my final result should be 9

because each array contain 9 keys

```
"nip",
"nama",
"semester1_2012",
"semester2_2012",
"semester1_2013",
"semester2_2013",
"semester1_2014",
"semester2_2014",
"semester1_2015"
```

I am new to AngularJS and have try length method but the result always greater than 9 because it counts the entire JSON

Comment: Have you tried the object.keys function ?

Comment: Just posted an answer. Please check out.

Comment: Uppsss my fault, forgot to put [0], It works.. Thank You very much Alvaro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function `Object.keys`

```
var length = 0;    

Object.keys(o).forEach(function(key) {
              var val = o[key];
             length = length + 1;

    });
```

Where `o` is any object.

In your case `o` should be any object of the array `$scope.listtalentapegawai` .

If you only want the `Length` you can do just like:

```
var length = Object.keys(o).length;
```

#### EDIT: your examples

```
.state('masterpegawai.alltalenta', {
            url: '/alltalenta',
            templateUrl: 'public/js/partial-masterpegawai-alltalenta.html',
            controller:function($scope,$http,$interval){
                    $http.get('http://10.16.107.77:3000/allhistorytalenta').success(function(data){

                        $scope.listtalentapegawai=data;

         var length = Object.keys($scope.listtalentapegawai[0]).length; // will be 9


                    });
            }
        })
```

Comment: Hi, Alvaro it return  : 3610 not 9

Comment: You can just use this. `var length = Object.keys(o).length;`

Comment: Still return greater than 9, I am expecting the result is 9 because every array have 9 keys

Comment: My final code is --> var length = Object.keys($scope.listtalentapegawai).length;
      $scope.panjang=length; when I put {{panjang}} the result is 3610 not 9

Comment: Uppsss my fault, forgot to put [0], It works.. Thank You very much Alvaro

Comment: @AriefGrando just updated the code. You have to pass an single object or any object in the array. Will work now in my update. You was passing the entire array. My example I just passed the first (position 0) from the array.

Comment: @AriefGrando I'm glad it helped you. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103251/discussion-between-arief-grando-and-alvaro-joao).